# Setting jdk version in eclipse maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I a new "mavenist"... :-)

I work with Eclipse Mars.

I created a default maven project, and it uses JDK 1.5 by default.
 I would like to use 1.8.31 instead.

My current POM shows the following:

```
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-testCompile</id>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

[On apache maven website](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) I read that I need to change\replace it to something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
      <compilerVersion>1.8.31</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

1. Is this the right code to put?
2. Should it replace the current code, or should I add it to the xml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough, taken from my very recent project.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You can have <plugins/> in  <pluginManagement/> and <build/>

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track but just override the options that you need to.

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Repeating *verbose, fork, executable etc.* isn't required.

Comment: And maybe an obvious question - it should replace the current code, right?

Comment: Actually the default pom generated by maven does not configure this plugin at all. So, if you know why the <executions> block was added (and it's serving some purpose) keep it. Otherwise you can replace the complete <plugin> block.

Comment: The pom.xml tab shows a very small XML file, which doesn't include any plugin. I took it from the "effective pom" tab version.

Comment: Okay, then you need to ignore the effective pom version and just add the xml block in my answer to your actual (small) pom.xml :)